# SQL query to get databases larger than a value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get all MySQL databases larger than 1.5GB and I am unable to come up with a query that compares the value returned by `ROUND((SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024),2)` with 1.50.

Any suggestions or advice will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what error you getting

Comment: Note that 1.5GB = 1000 * 1000 B. 1024 * 1024 B = 1 [GiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiB).

Comment: @DourHighArch you are off by 3 orders of magnitude

Comment: @ace please post all the significant code in your query and any error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also work

```
SELECT table_schema AS databaseName, 
   sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024/1024 AS sizeInGB
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema
HAVING sizeInGB >= 1.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

The query that you're using will give you the number of MB, not GB. So you can either convert your target from GB to MB **or** modify your query to give you GB instead of MB.

Either way, assuming that you're already doing something similar to the following…

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, SUM(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)/1024/1024 AS db_size_mb
FROM TABLES
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA
```

You simply need to add on `HAVING db_size_mb > xxxx` at the end. The value of xxxx would obviously depend on whether or not you're leaving the query as returning MB or not.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Note that I'm using a bitshift operator but only shifting 29 bits and then diving by 2 so that the precision is lost:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA AS db_name, 
    SUM((data_length + index_length) >> 29)/2 AS db_size_gb 
FROM TABLES
GROUP BY (TABLE_SCHEMA)
HAVING db_size_gb >= 1.5
```